# CakePHP and Checkstyle

Tags: cakephp, checkstyle

Can anyone recommend a ruleset.xml file that would be best for use with CakePHP? I was using the PEAR ruleset.xml, and tried out the Squiz ruleset.xml, but I was wondering if there's something specifically for CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not know much about it but there are two on github, which seem interesting.

<del>https://github.com/jrbasso/CodeSniffer_CakePHP/blob/master/ruleset.xml</del>

<del>https://github.com/AD7six/cakephp-codesniffs/blob/master/ruleset.xml</del>

**EDIT:**

The "official" CakePHP sniffs are now [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer)

Comment: Alternativly, there is [my Plugin](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-codesniffer) which on top has quite a few more sniffs and uses the new dev branch which auto-corrects found cs issues etc by itself.